# How to center text within a DIV vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="background: url('theImages/talentQuote.png') no-repeat center; background-size: 100% 100%; min-height: 125px; min-width: 125px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <span style="color: #FFF; font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="txtQuote" /></span>
</div>
```

Displays this:

[image]

How can I modify the CSS, so the quote is always centered within the background image

Comment: Duplicate of a very common question across the internet, search first ask questions later!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="bubble">
    <p>blablabla</p>
</div>

.bubble { 
  position: absolute; 
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 135px; 
  height: 84px; 
  display: table; 
}

.bubble p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLwzymmL/

Comment: Where do I add the padding around so the text doesn't overflow on to the DIV?

Comment: inside .bubble p{} / something like that: .bubble p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

Answer (score 2):

*It depends whether you want to center horizontally or vertically:*

**Horizontally** you should give these styles to the object:

**For text only:**

```
#parent {
text-align: center;
}
```

**For objects other than text:**

```
#child {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

**or:**

```
#child {
margin-left: 0 auto;
}
```

---

**Vertically** it's a bit more difficult, you have to set `display: table` to the parent and `display: table-cell` to the child, so that you can set the style `vertical-align: middle` to the child.

```
#parent {
display: table;
}

#child {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/beq3chhs/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your outter container to have `display:table;` and your inner container to have `display:tabe-cell;`

```
div{
    display:table;
    text-align: center; 
}

span{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`vertical-align: middle;` only works on table elements.

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/hLwzymmL/1/

```
.bubble p {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="middleelement">This is some text..</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
background: #008000;
background-size: 100% 100%;
text-align: center;
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 285px;
}
.middleelement {
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Se the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e16uhcrz/2/